# Default option for case sensitivity in ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, sql-order-by, case-sensitive

Lately, I observed a strange behavior of the `ORDER BY` clause in regard to case sensitivity.

A very simple query returns different results, depending on database:

```
SELECT company FROM DBT_COMPANY company ORDER BY company.name
```

I'm using Java EE + Hibernate + Oracle 11g/12c.

**The first database returns:**

> Amazon
>
> British Petroleum
>
> alpha

**The second database returns:**

> alpha
>
> Amazon
>
> British Petroleum

I know that I can fix the problem by using either `UPPER(company.name)` or `NLSSORT(company.name, 'NLS_SORT = BINARY_CI')` in the statement. However, I do not want to litter my Hibernate queries with those function calls.

I rather wonder, why both databases return different results in the first place. Is there any option for the default sort order on table or database level that might be misconfigured here?

Comment: What character sets do you use for DBs? And what value do you have for the `NLS_COMP` by default?

Comment: How can I check both, the character set and default value for `NLS_COMP`?

Comment: I have checked with `SELECT parameter, value FROM nls_session_parameters WHERE parameter IN ('NLS_COMP', 'NLS_SORT');` now. It returns the same setup on all databases.

Comment: I can not understand why you are looking some settings on the database level if you said : *When I run the SELECT statement manually, both databases sort as expected. The item order only varies, if the database is queried by Hibernate.*

Comment: Could you provide the code snippet how exactly you run the query from java, and your hibernate config.

Answer (score 0):

the default value is binary, so sb had to change it on one of the databases.
It can be changed by altering session or in initialization parameters.

```
alter session set NLS_COMP = 'ANSI';
alter session set NLS_SORT = 'BINARY_CI';
 
select * from (
select 'A' a from dual
union all
select 'B' from dual
union all
select 'a' from dual)
order by a;

--

alter session set NLS_COMP = 'BINARY';
alter session set NLS_SORT = 'BINARY';
 
select * from (
select 'A' a from dual
union all
select 'B' from dual
union all
select 'a' from dual)
order by a;

---

alter session set NLS_COMP = 'LINGUISTIC';
alter session set NLS_SORT = 'BINARY_CI';
 
select * from (
select 'A' a from dual
union all
select 'B' from dual
union all
select 'a' from dual)
order by a;
```

---

CHECK PARAMETERS ON YOUR INSTANCES AND SESSIONS:

```
SELECT DB.PARAMETER, DB.VALUE "DATABASE", I.VALUE "INSTANCE", S.VALUE "SESSION" FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS DB, NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS I, NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS S WHERE DB.PARAMETER=I.PARAMETER(+) AND DB.PARAMETER=S.PARAMETER(+) and db.parameter in ('NLS_SORT' , 'NLS_COMP');
```

If the intstance parameter and session are different it means that you IDE (SQL Developer? PL/Developer? Toad?) changes session NLS parameters.

SQL Developer -> tools -> preferences -> database -> NLS

Comment: When I run the `SELECT` statement manually, both databases sort as expected. The item order only varies, if the database is queried by Hibernate. Is there any permanent option for `NLS_COMP` and `NLS_SORT` on database-level?

Comment: Good read on this topic (only for reference): http://www.orafaq.com/node/999

Comment: how you run queries "on database"? SQL Developer or TOAD can change session parameters.
 
SELECT DB.PARAMETER, DB.VALUE "DATABASE", I.VALUE "INSTANCE", S.VALUE "SESSION"
FROM   NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS DB, NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS I, NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS S
WHERE  DB.PARAMETER=I.PARAMETER(+) AND DB.PARAMETER=S.PARAMETER(+)
and  db.parameter in ('NLS_SORT' , 'NLS_COMP');

there is comparision instance parameters and session parameters. Maybe youd IDE changes parameters (in sql developer tools-Preferences->database->NLS).